# Solving a system of three quadratic equations

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to get a tractable answer to:

```
Solve[
  w1^2*S1^2 + w2^2*S2^2 + w3^2*S3^2 + 2*w1*w2*S12 + 2*w1*w3*S13 + 2*w2*w3*S23 == SG^2 && 
  w1*S1P + w2*S2P + w3*S3P == SGP && 
  w1*ws1 + w2*ws2 + w3*ws3 == 1, 
  {w1, w2, w3}]
```

Mathematica produces a generic output which is like a thousand lines long.

Yet when I give it something like

```
Solve[
  w1^2*S1^2 + w2^2*S2^2 + w3^2*S3^2 + 2*w1*w2*S12 + 2*w1*w3*S13 + 2*w2*w3*S23 == SG^2 &&  
  w1*S1P + w2*S2P + w3*S3P == SGP && 
  w1*ws1 + w2*ws2 + w3*ws3 == 1 && 
  ws1 + ws2 + ws3 == 1 && 
  {S1, S2, S3, SG} > 0, 
  {w1, w2, w3}, Reals]`
```

the solver just hangs. The same goes for trying to simplify the generic output. Any ideas for getting a reasonable answer?

Comment: The answers given by Mathematica to your first code are correct. The answers really are that long. MMA does find 2 possibilities in the form `{{w1 --> stuff, w2 --> stuff, w3 --> stuff}, {w1 --> otherstuff, w2 --> otherstuff, w3 --> otherstuff}}`. You may be able to narrow it down to one of those. You might be able to make them look shorter with `FullSimplify` if that's all you're after.

Comment: Ug, that is disappointing. Well, it is what it is, thank you for checking. Since I plan on putting in actual numbers, it probably makes sense just to just solve it numerically whenever I need a solution.

Comment: `expr && {S1, S2, S3, SG}  >  0` is not the proper syntax. Use `expr && And @@ Thread[{S1, S2, S3, SG} > 0]`

Comment: Geez, I don't think this was a trivial question with a trivial answer that was easily found in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sol = Solve[
   w1^2*S1^2 + w2^2*S2^2 + w3^2*S3^2 + 2*w1*w2*S12 + 2*w1*w3*S13 + 
      2*w2*w3*S23 == SG^2 && w1*S1P + w2*S2P + w3*S3P == SGP && 
    w1*ws1 + w2*ws2 + w3*ws3 == 1, {w1, w2, w3}];

solS = sol // Simplify[#, Thread[{S1, S2, S3, SG} > 0]] &;

LeafCount /@ {sol, solS}

(* {37269, 6415} *)
```

Comment: Nailed it. I had no idea that was the correct syntax. Thank you!